# Does an app recognise database files that were created by other projects?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have two projects, in the first one i created a database successfully. My question is: is an app capable of processing this database if i copy the .db file from the first project to the location where all android apps save their databases
/data/data/pkgname/databases/yourdatabase.db?
or there would be some missing files?

Comment: Why don't you simply use a shared location and both your apps save and load their data to/from it? Anyway, yes, you can do that.

Comment: This comes up to me because I want to download the database .db files to use later on in my app.

Comment: So after having the .db files I can read and write as I used to?

Comment: Yes, unless the app doesn't use some cryptography. Another option is to import-export the data as CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to move your database file in public directory after  creating it, like sdcard.

Comment: Thanks all for response 